# ¿Cómo hacer funcionar un archivo .csv en google colab?

Tags: python, funciones, matrices, google-colab

tengo unas dudas con un código hecho en google colab. Resulta que hay que hacer un código y paralelamente un archivo .CSV en el que cada vez que termina de correr el código, se sobrescribe dentro del archivo .CSV. Les doy un ejemplo, la matriz que hice se trata de un almacén de productos donde se compran distintas cosas, entre ellas pan (por ejemplo), hay 20 productos existentes de pan. Al comprar 5 panes, dicha sustracción de identidades aparece dentro del código y el almacén queda con 15 panes (ya que compraron 5), entonces, al cerrar el programa, se guarda la información dentro del archivo .csv y se sobrescribe, de esa manera, al abrir nuevamente el programa, aparecen 15 panes ya que compraron 5 anteriormente.
Gracias por leer. Agradecería enormemente su ayuda!
Adjunto el código dentro de este mensaje.

````
Titulo = ['Nombre del Producto','Codigo del Producto','Cantidad del Producto','Precio del Producto']
matriz_datos = [[1,20,1000],[2,30,1500],[3,5,15000],[4,10,500],[5,40,1200],[6,15,2000],[7,2,2100],[8,0,200]]
lista_productos = ['Pan','Cecina','Whisky','Galletas','Papas Fritas','Chocolate','Coca-Cola','Chicles']
ganancia = 0
matriz_datos.insert(0,Titulo)```

```def inventario_productos():
    print('Inventario')
    
    for f in range(9):
       
        if f != 0:
            if type(matriz_datos[f][0]) == str:
                matriz_datos[f][0] = lista_productos[f-1]
            else:
                matriz_datos[f].insert(0,lista_productos[f-1])
        for c in range(4):
          
            print(format(matriz_datos[f][c],'^25'), end=' ')
        print()```

```def cambio_datos(posicion,cantidad):
    
    global ganancia
    cantidad_productos = matriz_datos[posicion][2]
    cantidad_productos = cantidad_productos - cantidad
    matriz_datos[posicion][2] = cantidad_productos
    ganancia = ganancia + (matriz_datos[posicion][3] * cantidad)```

```def validacion(opcion):
   
    if matriz_datos[opcion][2] != 0:
        print('\nIngrese la cantidad a vender:\n')
        cantidad = int(input())
        try:
            if cantidad>matriz_datos[opcion][2]:
                print(f'Escriba una cantidad menor o igual a {matriz_datos[opcion][2]}')
            elif cantidad == 0:
                print('Escriba una cantidad valida')
            elif cantidad < 0:
                print('Escriba una cantidad mayor a 0')
            else:
                cambio_datos(opcion,cantidad)
        except NameError:
            print(NameError)
    else:
        print('No hay suficientes existencias del producto')```

```def vender_producto():
    op = 0
    while op != 10:
        inventario_productos()
        print()
        print('*Sistema de Venta*')
        print('Seleccione el código del producto a vender: ')
        
        for lista in range(len(lista_productos)):
            print(f'{lista+1}.- {lista_productos[lista]}')
        print('10.- Salir\n')
        op = int(input())
        if op == 0:
            return inventario_productos()
        elif op == 1:
            validacion(op)
        elif op == 2:
            validacion(op)
        elif op == 3:
            validacion(op)
        elif op == 4:
            validacion(op)
        elif op == 5:
            validacion(op)
        elif op == 6:
            validacion(op)
        elif op == 7:
            validacion(op)
        elif op == 8:
            validacion(op)
        elif op == 10:
            ver_ganancias()
            print('\nSaliendo del sistema de ventas')
        else:
            print('\nNo existe el código ingresado. Seleccione una opción correcta: \n')
        print()```

```def ver_ganancias():
    global ganancia
    print(f'\nLa ganancia es de: ${ganancia}')```

```def menu():
    n = 0
    while n != 10:
        print('*Provisiones Alvin*')
        print('Escoja el numero de la opcion deseada')
        print('1.- Inventario de Productos')
        print('2.- Vender Producto')
        print('3.- Ver Ganancias')
        print('10.- Salir')
        print()
        n = int(input())
        
        if n == 1:
            print()
            inventario_productos()
        elif n == 2:
            print()
            vender_producto()
        elif n == 3:
            ver_ganancias()
        elif n ==10:
            ver_ganancias()
            print('\nSaliendo del Programa...')
        else:
            print('\nSeleccione una opción correcta')
        print()```


```with open('productos.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    lamatriz = csv.writer(csvfile)
    lamatriz.writerows(matriz_datos)```

menu()
````

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta o duda?

Comment: que cada vez que termino de correr el programa y quiero abrir el archivo "productos.csv" aparece "No se ha podido obtener productos.csv del backend" y un montón de detalles, y lo que quiero que aparezca dentro del csv es que al salir del programa, quede guardada la información que se modificó, pero no se por qué me aparece ese error

Comment: Pon el error específico _en la pregunta_. Y en lugar de escribir como título "duda con..." pon brevemente el problema en cuestión. Lee [ask].

Comment: ningún problema, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```
import linecache
pan = int(linecache.getline('nombre.css', 1))
tomate = int(linecache.getline('nombre.css', 2))
quitar = int(input('cuantos panes quieres'))
quitar2 = int(input('cuantos panes quieres'))
tomate = tomate - quitar2
pan = pan - quitar
archivo = open("nombre.css",'w')
archivo.writelines(str(pan))
archivo.writelines('\n') #salto de linea si quieres meter otro elemento tendra que poner delante del elemento nuevo uno de estos
archivo.writelines(str(tomate))
archivo.close()
```

esto es lo que entendi que querias que hiciese el programa si tienes algun problema con el arrobame y te respondo

Comment: agradezco tu ayuda Lucas pero lamentablemente no es ese el problema, lo de quitar elementos está incluido dentro del programa, pero necesito que se guarde dentro del archivo .csv que creé

Comment: simplemente ahora quitas nombre.css y pones el nombre de tu archivo .css entiendo que estas siguiendo un tutorial ya que realmente da igual que sea un txt un doc o lo que sea siempre y cuando pongas bien su nombre en los linecache.getline() y en el archivo = open("",'w') pero eso sitienes un problema o duda abisame en los comentarios de la publicacion

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).